# Django dynamic model design

Tags: django, database, database-design, model

I have a table that contains a dynamic number of entries, each entry contains data (like id, name, date) and also 3 radio buttons.

```
    class Entry(models.Model):
        id = ...
        name = ...
        data = ...
        selected_option = ...
```

I want to save all of the entries in the DB when the user submits the form.
I was wondering what would be the best way to design the model for this.

Comment: unless I'm missing something, your db schema looks fine.  you just need to have a form to automatically add extra entry options when the user indicates a desire to add more info

Comment: @Jason There are about 100 rows in the page and each one contains data like in the Entry class I've shown. I want that whenever the user submits the page, all of the 100 rows will go into the database as a whole.

Comment: ouch, ok.  I would seriously consider reviewing that user experience, because it sounds like a data entry nightmare.

Comment: @Jason Most of the fields are already filled, they just have to choose one of the options in each radio buttons set.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how your data looks like. It's not bad to store huge amount of data or structure your data. Let's say there are fixed number of options from which user will select the radio button right, you can store those options as choices in your db.

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    entry_id = ...
    name = ...
    date = ...

class SelectedOption(models.Model):
    class Options:
        OPTION_1 = 'O1'
        OPTION_2 = 'O2'
        Choices = (
           (OPTION_1, 'Option 1'),
           (OPTION_2, 'Option 2'),
        )

    option = CharField(choices=Options.Choices, max_length=2)
    entry = ForeignKey(Entry)
```

I think this way you won't have repetition of data. And your data will be more structured if you want to perform some analysis.

Comment: The options are brought from remote location, not from my local DB so I have to create them dynamically. There are 3 options in each entry, but there are about 100~ entries in a <table></table> that the user has to choose from